# How to condition fields in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce checkout form I have customized the fields. I have to show the fields depends on each category, in two categories (micro-loans, personal loans) all fields are shown. In the other categories only some are shown.

The total category is 6 (micro-loans, personal-loans, company loans, cards, savings-products, investment). I thought about conditionally organizing, but when I deleted a field using unset and another category required it, I could not do it.

The code that I have is the following:

```
function campos_checkout_condicional( $fields ){    
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {        
        $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );        

            if( has_term( array('micro-prestamos','prestamos-personales'), 'product_cat', get_post( $product_id ) ) ){
                return $fields;
            }

            if( has_term( 'tarjetas', 'product_cat', get_post( $product_id ) ) ){            
               unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
               unset($fields['billing']['billing_genero']);
            }
            if ( has_term( 'inversion', 'product_cat', get_post( $product_id ) ) ){
               $fields['billing']['billing_genero'];

            }   

    }
return $fields;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'campos_checkout_condicional' );
```

For example, if two different categories are added to the cart: 'Cards' and 'Inversion' in one, the 'genre' field is required, but in the other, it is not. There are other fields but to not extend this is a small example.

Will there be some way to do it better or to call the field in another condition?

Comment: I'd say that's the way to do it.

Comment: Thank you. I think it's the best way and do if-else sets, but will there be any way to override the unset function? What I have done is before anything an auxiliary variable that saves $ fields complete and then in a condition that needs a field already eliminated by unset, use that auxiliary variable but then everything erased returns.

Comment: If you unset it, then the field isn't available for that request. If you need the field, but don't want to show it, you could think about using hidden inputs.

Comment: You mean hide with 'display: none'? and I would have to deactivate validation because then I would jump error I suppose. The last thing I thought was to do about 16 conditional with the 4 categories, is not the most efficient evidently.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden